# yarn build shows empty page when building my react app?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I have created a website using create-react-app however when I try to run it using yarn build all I get is a blank white page and this error in the console:

"Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND   custom.css:1"

I have tried adding %PUBLIC_URL% to the ./custom.css and this hasn't worked, I have also tried to import the CSS directly into my App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import home from "./pages/home"
import about from "./pages/about"
import stats from "./pages/stats"
import contact from "./pages/contact"
import faq from "./pages/faq"
import login from "./pages/Login"
import signup from "./pages/SignUp"
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route
} from 'react-router-dom';

import './custom.css'

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Route exact path='/home' component={home} />
          <Route exact path='/about' component={about} />
          <Route exact path='/stats' component={stats} />
          <Route exact path='/faq' component={faq} />
          <Route exact path='/contact' component={contact} />
          <Route exact path='/signup' component={signup} />
          <Route exact path='/login' component={login} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Assistant:400,600,700,800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>StatHero</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="%PUBLIC_URL%/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "prototypesite",
  "homepage": "./",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.16",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "style": "^0.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

[image: This is where the CSS is normally]

[image: This is where the CSS is in the build]

Comment: Do any of your routes work, like the /home route? You also don't have a default route like <Route exact path='/' component={home} />

Comment: what would the URL be to check the /home route? And where do I add the default route? Sorry for the lack of knowledge I'm quite a beginner...

Comment: If your using the basic create react app it would be localhost:3000/home  and the default route would go on top of all your other routes in App.js.

Comment: When I run 'yarn start' the app works perfectly, the problem is when I use yarn build nothing appears... I tried uploading to Netlifly and once the site was published it was also blank white... Also I added the default route thank you.

Comment: Try to add `"homepage": ".",` in your `package.json` and build again.

Comment: I have added this to my json already, sorry ill edit the questions and add that in

Comment: Try to remove the *slash* `/` and only keep the *dot* `"homepage": "."` [Docs: building for relative paths](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths)

Comment: No luck with that either...

Comment: Please note that you'll need to rebuild your app again.

Comment: Yes I re-ran 'yarn build' in my terminal and then opened the index.html file in chrome to check if it was working

Comment: I guess I see the issue, this `<link href="%PUBLIC_URL%/custom.css" ...>` won't work because React is expecting `custom.css` to be inside `/public` folder not `/src` Try to remove that and add `import "./custom.css"` inside your `App.js` file.

Comment: When I add import "./custom.css" to the App.js it makes some of the CSS stop working when I run it locally? It doesn't do anything when I yarn build...